# Bigquery overlapping value distribution query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know if it is possible (and how) to get minimum distinct value overlap in range of values.

For instance lets say I have 3 bags of XY values in them, I would like a single (this is important, I know how to do it for each bag separately) query that gives me a percentage of exclusive values (in relation to all other bags) in each bag.

Here is an example

```
BAG | VALUE
1 | 100
1 | 102
1 | 100
2 | 100
2 | 101
2 | 101
3 | 103
3 | 103
3 | 102
3 | 104
```

So what I would get here is:

```
BAG | MINIMUM EXCLUSIVE VALUES
1 | 0  (no items here are exclusive)
2 | 0.5 (only item 101 is exclusive in this bag and since distinct count of all items in this bag is 2, 50% of the bag is exclusive)
3 | 0.666666 (items 103 and 104 are exclusive to this bag and since distinct count of all items in the bag is 3 this gives 66,66666% of exclusive items)
```

Is there any way to make this with single bigquery query (single as in I don't need to rewrite this query for each bag in a set since there can be quite a big number of bags). Of course query can have subqueries but it should not be tied (hardcoded) for each bag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max_bag as  BAG,
                sum(exclusive) / MAX(b.valuesPerBag) * 100 as percentValue,
                MAX(b.valuesPerBag) as countValues
from (
                select VALUE,
                               max( BAG) as max_bag,
                               if(min( BAG) == max( BAG), 1, 0) as exclusive
                from {TABLE_LIST}
                group by VALUE
) a
left join (
  select  BAG, integer(count( distinct VALUE)) as valuesPerBag
  from {TABLE_LIST}
  group by  BAG
) b on a.max_bag = b.BAG
group by  BAG
order by  BAG desc
```

Ok so this seems to be a viable solution based on upper ones. And it is quite optimized as well. I haven't done all tests yet so I won't put it as accepted answer but from a few tests we made this seems correct.

EDIT:
Done some testing, this was the fastest solution on 8mil items and 500 bags.

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of @N.N.'s solution:

```
SELECT BAG, SUM(is_unique)/MAX(CVB) as MINIMUM_EXCLUSIVE_VALUES
FROM
    (
    SELECT BAG, VALUE, MAX(IF(CBV=1,1,0)) as is_unique , MAX(CVB) as CVB
    FROM
        (
        SELECT BAG,
                VALUE,
                Count(Distinct BAG) OVER(Partition BY VALUE) as CBV, 
                Count(Distinct VALUE) OVER(Partition BY BAG) as CVB
         FROM 
          (Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
          (Select 1 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
          (Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
          (Select 2 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
          (Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
          (Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
          (Select 3 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
          (Select 3 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
          (Select 3 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
          (Select 3 as BAG, 104 AS VALUE),
         ORDER BY BAG
         )
    GROUP BY BAG, VALUE
)
GROUP BY BAG
```

Comment: While your answer (and below one) are technically correct I don't know if i can say this is an answer because on 8,000,000 rows of which there are 2000 bags and 800000 different values (entire data size is about 280MB) my query after 10minutes is still executing... I hope they don't bill me like terabytes of processing :)

Comment: Wow 30min and still executing! I will try to get support to cancel the query!

Comment: Did you try group each by instead of group by?

Comment: No need to panic, if your table is ±280MB in size then this is the max amount of processed data you'll be billed:)

Comment: @RadekMichna that is pretty awesome news. Can you provide source for this?

Comment: @Rohit https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries (Sample query costs)

Comment: Just to give an update, my queries after an 90min on 8mil rows ended in "ERROR: unexpected"... Since I have paid support I submitted a ticket to clarify this error so when I get more info I will update. Same for GROUP EACH BY...

Answer (score 1):

```
Select BAG,VALUE, IF(CNT_BagsPerValue>1,0,CNT/CNT_ValuesPerBag) as MIN_EXCLUSIVE_VALUES
FROM
(Select BAG,VALUE,CNT_BagsPerValue,CNT_ValuesPerBag,Count(*) as CNT
FROM
(
Select BAG,VALUE,--Count(*) as CNT,
Count(Distinct BAG) OVER(Partition BY VALUE) as CNT_BagsPerValue
, Count(Distinct VALUE) OVER(Partition BY BAG) as CNT_ValuesPerBag
from 
(Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
(Select 1 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
(Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
(Select 2 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
(Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
(Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 104 AS VALUE),
)
GROUP BY BAG,VALUE,CNT_BagsPerValue,CNT_ValuesPerBag,)
```

Comment: Not there yet. It still doesn't match OP's ask.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select max_bag, sum(exclusive) / count(*) from
(select value, max(bag) as max_bag, if(min(bag) == max(bag), 1, 0) as exclusive
from 
  (Select 0 as BAG, 0 AS VALUE),
  (Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
  (Select 1 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
  (Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
  (Select 2 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
  (Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
  (Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
  (Select 3 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
  (Select 3 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
  (Select 3 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
  (Select 3 as BAG, 104 AS VALUE)
group by value
)
group by max_bag
```

the only problem is that this will omit results where the distribution is equal to zero (bag 1 in this case). I hope this should be able to process your data in seconds (you might need use group each by).

EDIT:

```
select bag, sum(exclusive) / max(dist_in_bag) from
(select bag, value, dist_in_bag, if(x == y, 1, 0) as exclusive from
(select bag, value, dist_in_bag, min(bag) over(partition by value) as x, max(bag) over(partition by value) as y from
(select bag, value, count(*) over(partition by bag) as dist_in_bag from
(Select 0 as BAG, 0 AS VALUE), 
(Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE), 
(Select 1 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE), 
(Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE), 
(Select 2 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE), 
(Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE), 
(Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE), 
(Select 3 as BAG, 108 AS VALUE), 
(Select 3 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE), 
(Select 3 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE), 
(Select 0 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE), 
(Select 0 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE), 
(Select 0 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE), 
(Select 0 as BAG, 104 AS VALUE), 
(Select 4 as BAG, 203 AS VALUE), 
(Select 4 as BAG, 203 AS VALUE), 
(Select 4 as BAG, 202 AS VALUE), 
(Select 4 as BAG, 204 AS VALUE)
group by bag, value
)))
group by bag
```

Comment: This actually does something! Can you verify that this gives percentage only on DISTINCT values?

Comment: Uh, I was happy too early. It doesn't really work for minimum and maximum bag numbers.

Comment: (Select 0 as BAG, 0 AS VALUE),
(Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
(Select 1 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
(Select 1 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
(Select 2 as BAG, 100 AS VALUE),
(Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
(Select 2 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 108 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
(Select 3 as BAG, 101 AS VALUE),
(Select 0 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
(Select 0 as BAG, 103 AS VALUE),
(Select 0 as BAG, 102 AS VALUE),
(Select 0 as BAG, 104 AS VALUE),
(Select 4 as BAG, 203 AS VALUE),
(Select 4 as BAG, 203 AS VALUE),
(Select 4 as BAG, 202 AS VALUE),
(Select 4 as BAG, 204 AS VALUE)

Comment: @lord.fist yes you are right... there is problem, I'll try to update it to be correct

Comment: For upper data bag 0 shouldn't have 100% exclusivity since value 102 exists in bag 1 as well...

Comment: @lord.fist just have added another version, but this one is not much optimal

Comment: I have added a solution based on your solution which is more optimized :)